# labels are not updating on Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms

In a math game that I programming, my Windows Form has labels in it where the numbers appear for the sum.

When I click `button1`, they should change to other numbers, but they don't. The labels that should change are called `lblNumber1` and `lblNumber2`.

Here is my code:

```
    public partial class plussommen : Form
    {
        int counter = 0;
        int correct = 0;
        int incorrect = 0;
        Random rand = new Random();
        int number1, number2;
        int answer;
        string sum;

        public plussommen()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            number1 = rand.Next(1, 50);
            number2 = rand.Next(1, 50);
            sum = number1 + " + " + number2 + " = ";
            answer = number1 + number2;
        }

        private void plussommen_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (counter < 5)
            {
                lblNumber1.Text = number1.ToString();
                lblNumber2.Text = number2.ToString();
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblCorrect.Text = correct.ToString();
            lblIncorrect.Text = incorrect.ToString();

            if (textBox1.Text == answer.ToString())
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Answer correct!");
                correct = correct + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Answer incorrect!");
                incorrect = incorrect + 1;
            }

            if (counter < 5)
            {
                lblNumber1.Text = number1.ToString();
                lblNumber2.Text = number2.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                if (counter == 5)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("You've made five sums, choose another kind of sum.");
                    this.Close();
                    Form1 menu = new Form1();
                    menu.Show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is teller < 5? What's in getal1 and getal2?

Comment: I don't see any loop. Are you sure to have written everything? Or you missed something?

Comment: Yes teller is < 5, look, int teller = 0;

Comment: "Why is my code not working" is of topic questions

Comment: I am making a loop using the if statement, i dont know how to code it another way

Comment: Nothing jumps out with a quick look.  Learn to use the debugger so you can see what value are changing and exactly what code is being executed.

Comment: I don't see any logic changing the values of `getal1` and `getal2` after the constructor, so they'd always stay the same.

Comment: @Reniuz Yes, but it is only off-topic if it does not contains the input/output, behavior and necessary code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: getal1 and getal2 need to change because you need to see a new sum..

Comment: @TheVuurwerk4life An `if` statement is not a loop. Lookup `for` and `foreach`. Those operators are for loops.

Comment: So, it sounds like each button click you increment. It's not technically a loop. @DStanly is correct, if you put a breakpoint in your _Click event, step through what is happening. It should greatly help in determining the issue. From an initial look, I don't see you incrementing teller anywhere, so you probably just need to do that as the first line in click.

Comment: @TheVuurwerk4life Please review the provided answers, and accept the correct answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

To change the value on the labels on every click, you need to generate new random numbers each time.

```
if (counter < 5)
{
    number1 = rand.Next(1, 50);
    number2 = rand.Next(1, 50);
    lblNumber1.Text = number1.ToString();
    lblNumber2.Text = number2.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are not changing the values of `number1` and `number2` at any time after initialization. This is why they are not updating after every button click.

What you need to do is update the numbers and the answer after every click:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //...
    if (counter < 5)
    {
        number1 = rand.Next(1, 50);
        number2 = rand.Next(1, 50);
        answer = number1 + number2;
        lblNumber1.Text = number1.ToString();
        lblNumber2.Text = number2.ToString();
    }
    //...
}
```